# Why is my proxied TCP connection returning empty bytes?

Tags: go, http, tcp, proxy, network-programming

I am building a system where I have a forward proxy that forwards TCP traffic to a websocket, which again forwards it to the target host. The intention of this is to allow any computer on any network to act as a forward proxy (regardless of whether the computer/network is publicly accessible, just so long as it allows outbound traffic). The flow is as follows:

```
1. Proxy opens connection with server
2. Client attempts to proxy request to server
3. Server accepts connection and handles CONNECT
4. Server acts as middleman between client and proxy, just streaming bytes
```

I have tried to implement this in Go, with one caveat: The server reaches out to the proxy, as opposed as the proxy opening a connection with the server. This is just so that it's easier to develop. I anticipate this will be easy to switch around since websocket connections are bi-directional.

The problem I am running into is that the proxy, when reading bytes from the target host, just keeps reading zero bytes. It appears to be sending the correct bytes to the target host. Here is my code (I am using gorilla/websocket):

```
// Server
func main() {
    proxy := func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        client, _, err := w.(http.Hijacker).Hijack()
        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(502)
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        if req.Method == http.MethodConnect {
            client.Write([]byte("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n"))
        }
        if req.URL.Port() == "" {
            req.URL.Host += ":80"
        }
        ws, err := NewC(req.URL.Host)
        if err != nil {
            w.WriteHeader(400)
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        ioCopy(client, ws)
    }
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":5001", http.HandlerFunc(proxy)))
}

type RWCloser interface {
    io.Reader
    io.Writer
    io.Closer
}

func ioCopy(client net.Conn, ws RWCloser) {
    go func() {
        if _, err := io.Copy(ws, client); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Ws to client error", err)
            return
        }
        client.Close()
    }()
    go func() {
        for {
            if _, err := io.Copy(io.MultiWriter(client, os.Stdout), ws); err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Client to ws error", err)
                break
            }
        }
        ws.Close()
    }()
}

var _ RWCloser = (*C)(nil)

type C struct {
    conn *websocket.Conn
}

func NewC(targetUrl string) (*C, error) {
    conn, _, err := websocket.DefaultDialer.Dial("ws://localhost:5000", nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    conn.WriteMessage(websocket.BinaryMessage, []byte(targetUrl))
    return &C{conn}, nil
}

func (c *C) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    _, message, err := c.conn.ReadMessage()
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    copy(p, message)
    return len(message), nil
}

func (c *C) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    err = c.conn.WriteMessage(websocket.BinaryMessage, p)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return len(p), nil
}

func (c *C) Close() error {
    return c.conn.Close()
}
```

```
// Websocket Server
var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handleWebSocket)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":5000", nil))
}

func handleWebSocket(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    client, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    _, hostBytes, err := client.ReadMessage()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        client.Close()
        return
    }
    host := string(hostBytes)
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", host)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        client.Close()
        return
    }

    go func() {
        for {
            _, msg, err := client.ReadMessage()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                break
            }
            _, err = conn.Write(msg)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                break
            }
        }
        client.Close()
    }()

    go func() {
        for {
            var msg []byte
            _, err := conn.Read(msg)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                break
            }
            fmt.Println(string(msg)) // Logs []
            err = client.WriteMessage(websocket.BinaryMessage, msg)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                break
            }
        }
        conn.Close()
    }()
}
```

```
// Request
func main() {
    proxyURL, err := url.Parse("http://localhost:5001")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    httpClient := &http.Client{
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyURL),
        },
    }
    response, err := httpClient.Get("https://example.com/")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    log.Println("Response status:", response.Status)
}
```

I would appreciate some pointers on how to solve this, as I have been unable to figure it out for a while now.

Comment: There are no "empty bytes", a byte must have a value but you are printing no bytes at all. You are reading into an nil (zero-length) slice, so you can't read any bytes. You are also calling `_, err := conn.Read` and ignoring the number of bytes read, so if you had a valid slice you would be using the wrong output anyway. (you should also create the read buffer outside a loop, rather than allocating a new one every time)

Comment: I had no idea that was how reading worked, I assumed it would copy as many as it could. Thanks!!

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at the [`io.Reader` documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader), and some basic networking examples

Comment: Would you be able to provide me with an example of what it should look like? Or a link to something similar? EDIT Sent that message at the same time as the previous one, thanks.

Comment: There are loads of examples online of how to read and write from a TCP stream, I would familiarize yourself with some basic networking concepts before adding the complication of the proxy here. Another problem is that you are returning immediately from your `handleWebSocket`, which invalidates the client connection. You must handle all reading and writing of the request within the lifespan of the handler.

Comment: I think it makes a lot more sense for me to just use another TCP stream, instead of trying to shoehorn in a WebSocket. Thanks again for your help.